# Why "Is there any Civilization-like game for the Wii?" was closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

Why [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5903/is-there-any-civilization-like-game-for-the-wii) was Closed?

It's not like there's a long list of Wii games that are Civ-like or even turn-based-strategy.
In the end, there should be one game recommendation. I mean, yes there is one; here it is and move along.

And, if it's not acceptable, why accept "game recommendations" in the first place? I mean, I don't think it's a "List of X" question.

**Update:**

It' now marked as a community Wiki and been sightly rephrased.

It appear it has been closed becose of that, but also for because it's a game recommendation question

Is a just been reopned (24 august 2010) 
But I fear it will be re-closed soon.

Comment: We generally try not to accept game recommendations in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly I think asking for a game-recommendation is bad (not just for the asker but the site in general).

Now I know at least one other question was fine based on the fact that the correct answer is: there really is only one (actually two now).  I'd like to discourage people trying to squeeze game recommendations in by saying: I've narrowed it down so there is only one answer, as that only introduces a flood of questions of this type, and really those questions are just as bad as any other game rec (ie. little more than opinions).

In your case you asked for "Is there any other turn-based-strategy game on the Wii?" and the reality is there are 100s.  But even if you narrowed the question down further to something like "Are there any other turn-based-strategy games on the Wii where you build an empire and research technologies to advance the units you can produce?" I don't really think that's any better of a question.

At the end of the day you want a recommendation for a game to play, and recommendations are just opinions.  Whether or not you enjoy the recommendation is also an opinion.  No one else could pick a correct answer for that question besides you, even if they had access to your set up.

Its too personal.

---

Edit: for clarity here is the [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5976) we did decide was ok.  While still borderline, the question was ultimately "does the map making capabilities exist on the 360," and the real answer there is that "Not explicitly, but a game maker could put them in."

Comment: OK, if game recommendation are not accepted. but, It should be clear.Since "What are other pc games along the genre as Hitman?" was voted a "Great on topic" example 7 times on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?phase=definition I thought they where accepted.

Comment: The problem is with the only provided answer is that is a game for the virtual console. A game for TurboGrafx-16 released in 1990. I don`t think running a game running in an emulator (built-in or not) cont as a "Wii Game". So it's not "actually two now"

Comment: On a gaming site...why is it that if someone asks if there are any type of X on Platform Y it is disallowed?  Instead of pointing people to Google, you should be welcoming them with open arms and allowing those with knowledge of the topic to chip in.  

It's no coincidence that on sites like Reddit, lists are among the most popular topics.  I thought the community wiki would be great for a question like this.  Can you imagine the hits if you left it open and got 30 replies?

Comment: @DaveRob60 So initially we thought that game-rec would be a good idea, and until you try it out its hard to know.  As for why they're bad I'll answer in a second comment.

Comment: @Corv1nus It would be nice if we could just support everything, and had a 1 stop shop for all questions gaming.  However, this is a serious Q&A site, not a collection site for lists of game.  There are other sites on the internet which fill that Niche. What's more game-rec questions are in fact poisonous to establishing a site with expert responses. An expert wants a site where having knowledge is important not a site where any opinion goes. This is the reason Yahoo Answers is such a bad resource, despite supporting the same functionality. Game-rec's are opinions, they require no knowledge.

Comment: @Corv1nus I give a longer explanation of why Game-rec's are bad here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302/game-recommendations-and-single-correct-answers/767#767

Comment: @All You get it wrong. This question is not about a Game List, my point is That I cannot find ANY Game That fits those criteria. The answer I was seeking is not "There is this game and This game" But, "Yes, and there is this game as an example". Anyway, I edited the question has a community wiki hoping that would fits the criteria to move further.

Comment: @DaveRob60 first off, http://www.gamespot.com/games.html?type=games&category=Turn-Based+Strategy&platform=1031  Secondly, its not any better of a question.  You'll say "X fits," or "X doesn't fit" and someone else will say "yes it does," and the truth is you're both right.  Its subjective.  The answers will only have value to the person choosing them.  Even if you narrow the criteria down so you feel there is only one answer, that's still your opinion.  Its not worthwhile to anyone but you.

Comment: @tzenes OK, got your point. I now fully understand why those kind of question are bad.

Comment: @DaveRob60 if you ever want to talk about it more you can find me in chat.meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @DavRob60 it's not that game recommendations are not accepted, it's that there's an active debate on their future. You can read more in [the question tzenes linked](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302/game-recommendations-and-single-correct-answers). Notice that currently the highest voted answer does not forbid these questions altogether.

Comment: @Oak : That why I switched it to community wiki. I don't think this question is "too broad"

Comment: @tzenes: by the way the link you provided is useless. In that list, there's at least one canceled games (Sid Meier's Civilization Revolution ) and a lot of "strategy RPG". And WTF! Calling "Pokemon Battle Revolution" a "Turn Based Strategy" is like saying that "Mortal Kombat" is "real time strategy".

Comment: @tzenes I see what you are getting at.  The problem I have with it is the definition you use of expert and the assumption of what an expert wants.  As you state it the term is purely subjective.  I consider myself a gaming expert.  I've been playing for 25 years and ~30 hours a week for that entire span.  I've even developed games.  I would like to see the answers to that question on here.  It's not something that can't be found using Google but, I could argue the same for 90% of the questions on the site. If the community says no go on it, I won't push it further but, I will never agree to it

Comment: @DaveRob60 that you think those games aren't turn based strategy is your opinion, which is what really gets to the crux of the matter.  There is no way to say definitively, these are or these are not.

Comment: @Corv1nus if you followed the link I provided you would have seen a case study.  It is not the only one you'll see I have provided here on Meta.  While you may consider yourself an "expert" if we look at websites which have established themselves as experts in the gaming community (ElitistJerks, TeamLiquid, etc), we see a trend of having low tolerance for opinions.  It is no coincidence that these sites have extreme moderation policies.  The bottom line is, do we want to be a serious Q&A site, or a site that just let's in anything gaming?

Comment: @Grace that is an argument I can see and live with.  

@tzenes I read your link and it is an interesting case study.  I tend to disagree because I like broader questions but, if that is the direction the site is going then that is the choice to be made.  Additionally, sneer quoting me will only cause conflict between myself and you (I didn't realized I had to list my history of clans, pro matches, and gaming sites I've helped as well).  Neither one of us wants that, it's bad for the site.

Comment: Waah, I didn't think anyone would've caught that in the 3 minutes it was up. I'll repost that comment that Corv1nus is responding to...

Comment: The reason why "genre X on platform Y" and other repository questions are generally a bad idea is because [we are very poor at handling them](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/818/what-level-of-exclusion-is-healthy-for-the-site-at-this-point/819#819). People expect a lot more than what the Stack Exchange engine can provide while simultaneously handling "standard Q&A". They want ratings, one-per-answer, extra information, and a host of other elements. But our overloaded vote system and non-supportive navigation are but two of many elements that make us very bad at repositories.

Comment: @tzenes : I not asked for "turn based strategy", I asked for "turn based strategy Like Civilization". That why normal/arbitrary classification (like the one in the link you provided) don't fit.

Comment: @Corv1nus I didn't mean that comment as a sneer and if you took offense to it I apologize.  I was trying to suggest that using yourself as an example is not very good evidence.

Comment: @DaveRob60 your original question asked for "turn based strategy," but ignoring that, what if I think Pokemon Battle Arena is a "turn based strategy Like Civilization?" It is certainly my opinion on the matter (for reference I don't) and I am entitled to it.  What you consider "like Civilzation" and what I do are two different things.

Comment: @tzenes Well, from that point, almost anything become subjective.

Comment: @All Is that Question Doomed or there some modifications that could make it reopen?

Comment: @DavRob60 all recommendations certainly.  The issue here is not that people have opinions, but rather that people's preferences on games and where they draw connections are largely subjective. I may think Sacrifice is the greatest RTS of all time, where as you may think of it as an FPS given the presentation.  There is no expert knowledge here, there is only opinion.

Comment: @tzenes Also, all question on Strategy, tactic. Like in your question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5613/whats-the-best-way-to-grind-xp-in-dynasty-warriors-6 You are asking for the "best Way". Best for Who? you? on witch criteria? Fastest way or easiest way? I take one of your question (please not take it personally) just to show you that there is always a level of subjectivity, the the problem is to not be too subjective. We could argue on what is a "turn based strategy Like Civilization", You could have an opinion on that subject, but what I mean could be defined in the question.

Comment: We are drifting out of the subject, What made that question closed and hou could it be fixed. If it was closed because it have the Game-rec tag, well fine. just said no more game-rec and that all. but i removed the must subjective element and put it as a wiki. http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302/game-recommendations-and-single-correct-answers said that it should be ok, no?

Comment: @tzenes It's all good.  @DavRobo60 I voted to reopen now that it is a wiki but, I think the problem is that it is closed because it is not a question that requires an expert answer in the manner of something like say, "How do I calculate how to run armor in Quake Live?"

Comment: @DavRob60 as I mentioned, people have opinions, that's not really the issue here.  The question "What’s the Best Way to Grind XP in Dynasty Warriors 6" requires a level of expertise, of knowledge of the game.  Knowing how much xp you gain in an level, or through a method is not a subjective fact. The issue is not that the question itself is subjective, but that the answers are.  If it were an issue of the question, you could just rephrase, but as the question leads to subjective answers its a "bad question." (I don't mean to characterize you as bad, just the nature of the question).

Comment: @Corv1nus if you include 2 @ in you comment, only the first one is ping'd.

Comment: Bummer, that kind of stinks.  Re-adding...@DavRobo60 I voted to reopen now that it is a wiki but, I think the problem is that it is closed because it is not a question that requires an expert answer in the manner of something like say, "How do I calculate how to run armor in Quake Live?"

Comment: @tzenes ok, but how it's different form http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/any-dungeon-design-games-out-there http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/what-are-some-games-that-are-similar-to-the-arcade-classic-marble-madness and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/browser-based-mmorpg-with-strong-economy-strategy-element

Comment: For those of you who weren't in the chat when I explained this, both of those questions should be closed.  One was and then reopened, the other has not attracted enough attention to be closed.

Comment: Addition from tzenes last comment:  tzenes believe those question should be closed. But they where reopened by other users who believe the opposite. The status of Game-Rec question is still controversial and the community will play with that Switch until a consensus is achieved. (I, for one, did not made a definitive decision on the subject.)

Comment: @DavRob60 what you say is true.  I speak for myself not the community at large.  Other people have already stated that this subject had not been decided upon, what's more a quick look at meta will show many of these questions still open.

Answer (score 0):

The original question asked for games "that I would like". However once that phrase is edited out (as it is now) the question becomes neutral, objective, and factual. It simly asks for games "like Civilisation" (turn-based, strategy, large-scale) for the Wii. I see no problem with asking questions loke this on a site like this, and I would even be interested in the answer.

Closing a question when it could be fixed by a simple edit is aggressive, unfriendly and discouraging to the asker; it is also restrictive to the site.

Comment: You pointed something that annoyed me, It make the asker feels childish. I mean, I felt like my son when I ignore is request because he dis not said "please". Maybe some closed it on that purpose, but it look like the issue is beyond that.