# Question closed for being too specific?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5297/roguelike-for-android) is closed, apparently because it is too specific (although neither of the closers who left comments did a good job of explaining why it had been closed.)

Can we just clarify if and why this question should be closed?

[edit: the question has been reopened, but I'm still not sure what criteria decide whether game rec questions are off topic]

Comment: It should be noted that Gnoupi, who said it was specific, was *defending* your question alongside Jeffrey.

Comment: Exactly. It wasn't closed for being too specific, it was closed for being too **general**.

Comment: Yep, I apologised to Gnoupi on the original thread. I don't read things carefully enough obviously...

Comment: In fact, the people who voted to close really _should_ have commented to explain why they voted to close it. Not very good that none of them deigned to comment...

Comment: [♪](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/869/check-the-comments-not-the-question "Check the comments~ ♪").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify why the question *was* closed, it is most likely because the question is [yet](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/why-is-there-any-civilization-like-game-for-the-wii-was-closed) [another](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/529/re-open-a-question) [repository](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/what-makes-my-question-a-real-question), not entirely because of the estimated answer yield. If you'll note my comment on that question, I explain why that metric is also stupid for both closing and reopening anyway. The scope of the question, which is genre X on platform Y, is what should be judged on, not the fact that platform Y is not likely to have a large number.

So should the question *remain* closed? There's no solid judgment. There's a lot of back-and-forth going on about whether game recommendations and listings are appropriate. Please check out the earlier 3 links for reasons on closing given by some of the community. Also check out [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/what-level-of-exclusion-is-healthy-for-the-site-at-this-point/819#819), where I explain why I personally think we are horrendously poor at supporting repositories, and [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/re-evaluating-our-site-what-is-the-scope-of-an-acceptable-list-if-it-exists) [selection](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/game-recommendations-and-single-correct-answers) [of](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/776/voting-on-the-future-of-list-of-x-questions) [discussions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/799/do-we-have-personal-problems-with-polls-listt-game-rec-questions-or-is-it-habit) with voices on both sides of the debate.

Comment: It's Fünf, not Funf.

Comment: @badp Fixed. At least I can pronounce it a lot better than I can write it.

Comment: great, because I can't do either :D

Comment: I have to agree compeltely.  While I agree with the general rule, a list of that nature is quite specific and most definitely not large.  I think something like "What are some cool games for the Android?" would be an example of a bad question that would need to be closed.